# How to isolate numbers separated by stars in Lua?

Tags: arrays, string, lua, coronasdk

In some web service, I receive this

> "time":"0.301*0.869*1.387*2.93*3.653*3.956*4.344*6.268*6.805*7.712*9.099*9.784*11.071*11.921*13.347*14.253*14.965*16.313*16.563*17.426*17.62*18.114"

I want to separate the numbers and insert them into a table like this, how ?

```
0.301
0.869
1.387
2.93
3.653
3.956
4.344
6.268
6.805
7.712
9.099
9.784
11.071
11.921
13.347
14.253
14.965
16.313
16.563
17.426
17.62
18.114
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little string-matching should get the job done:

```
local str = [["time":"0.301*0.869*1.387*2.93*3.653*3.956*4.344*6.268*6.805*7.712*9.099*9.784*11.071*11.921*13.347*14.253*14.965*16.313*16.563*17.426*17.62*18.114"]]

local list = {}

for num in str:gmatch("%**(%d+%.%d+)") do
table.insert(list, tonumber(num))
end
```

---

**A Little Explanation**

I'll first briefly summarize what some of the symbols here are:

`%d` this means to look for a specific digit.

`%.` means to look specifically for a period

`+` means to look for 1 or more of the specific thing you wanted to match earlier.

`%*` means to look specifically for a star.

`*` when the percentage sign isn't in front, this means that you can match 0 or more of a specific match.

---

Now, let's put this together to look at it from the start:

`%**` This means that we want the string to start with a star, but it that is optional. The reason we need it to be optional is because the first number you wanted does not have a star in front of it.

`%d+` means to look for a sequence of digit(s) until something else pops up. In our case, this would be like the '18' in '18.114' or the '1' in '1.387'

`%.` as I said means we want the next thing found to be a period.

`%d+` means we want another sequence of digit(s). Such as the `114` in `18.114`

So, what do the parenthesis mean? It just means that we don't care about anything else outside the parenthesis when we capture the pattern.

Comment: good, but can you explain what is inside the gmatch ?
any explanation if i want to do my own different match in the future?

Comment: See the lua manual on this topic: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1.
The %** matches any number of * (%* is a literal *), but is in fact not needed in this case. You can simply match the numbers. The numbers consist of a bunch of digits (%d), of which there have to be at least one (+), then a literal dot (%.), then again a bunch of numbers. The hole match is captured, therefore the () are added around the numbers.

Comment: You are inserting strings into table, not numbers.

Comment: If you know that the numbers are well-formed, then the simpler pattern `"[%d.]+"` works fine.

Comment: can you please explain to me how to seperate words between spaces? gmatch("%s") or gmatch("%ss") don't work for me.

Comment: @DigitalVeer : i want to separate arabic words, i managed to separate english ones with no problem, please see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652593/how-to-isolate-non-english-words-separated-by-spaces-in-lua