# How to isolate non english words separated by spaces in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, find, coronasdk, lua-patterns

I have this string

```
"Hello there, this is some line-aa."
```

how to slice it into an array like this?

```
Hello
there,
this
is
some
line-aa.
```

this is what I have tried so far

```
function sliceSpaces(arg)
  local list = {}
  for k in arg:gmatch("%w+") do
    print(k)
    table.insert(list, k)
  end
  return list
end

local sentence = "مرحبا يا اخوتي"
print("sliceSpaces")
print(sliceSpaces(sentence))
```

**this code works for English text**, but not for arabic, how can I make it work for arabic too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua strings are sequences of bytes, not Unicode characters. The pattern `%w` matches alphanumeric characters, but it applies to ASCII only.

Instead, use `%S` to match a non-whitespace character:

```
for k in arg:gmatch("%S+") do
```

Comment: @DeyaEldeen Yes, since `+` matches one or more. However, note that one Arabic character actually are 2 or more bytes, depending on the encoding.